# How to use javax.swing.JProgressBar to start at a certain time and finish at a certain time?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jprogressbar

I'm new to Java and I'm building a program that works as basically a real-time schedule. What it does is displays the event, followed by a progress bar, the time of the event (such as 8:00 - 9:00) and the time left in the event. How would I program the progress bars to start at, let's say, 8:00 and progress and complete at 9:00? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of the current code.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea would be to calculate the percent of the time interval that has passed, and call `setProgress()` on the `JProgressBar` with the calculated percent.

You would definitly want to use a `Timer` to check at a regular interval.

Answer (score 1):

Java tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html